# Uncaught Exception: Range Error in Highcharts Not Resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, dynamics-365

This is the code I am using:

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    renderTo: 'container',
    backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('plotline-target');

      },
      drillup: function(e) {

        chart.yAxis[0].update({
          max: 100,
          plotLines: [{
            color: '#85F034',
            width: 2,
            //value: dfi_Top3Supplier,
            //id: 'plotline-target',
            label: {
              text: 'Target - ' + dfi_Top3Supplier,
            }
          }]

        });
      }
    }

  },
  title: {
    text: '% Top 3 Supplier'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#003399',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: {
      text: ''
    },

    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value + "%";
      }
    },
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#85F034',
      width: 3,
      //value: dfi_Top3Supplier,
      id: 'plotline-target',
      label: {
        text: 'Target - ' + dfi_Top3Supplier,
      }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
      }
    },
    line: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      enableMouseTracking: true
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Won',
    colorByPoint: false,
    color: '#000000',
    data: SupplierArray
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: SupplierDrilldown,
    drillUpButton: {
      relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
      position: {
        y: -5,
        x: -50
      },
      theme: {
        fill: 'white',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        stroke: 'silver',
        r: 0,
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: '#bada55'
          },
          select: {
            stroke: '#039',
            fill: '#bada55'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
}
```

I face an Uncaught Range Error exception if I display data for the last 12 months, but if I display data for the last 6 months then it works well. I need help! Actually I am binding X and Y-axis dynamically. So it will give the same error in two of the charts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
When asking for debugging help, we ask that you condense your code by making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
This is helpful for people to understand your problem without having to go through the whole code.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor that the community will be able to work on?